# Python decode from a specific string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, decode

Someone gave me this string: "Al BaÅ£á¸©ah" (it's probably an Arabic name),
and asked me to translate it (and a list of other similar strings) in Python.

This [website](https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode) converts it to "Al Baţḩah" with the operation "UTF8 Decode".  I'm trying to do the same in Python, but is what I tried and my results.  Most of the examples took a series of unicode bytes. I tried the "detect" to see exactly what it is he was giving me. If it's already UTF8, then I'm not sure what that website is convert it to.

```
import chardet

byte_string = b"\x61\x62\x63"
decoded_string = byte_string.decode("utf8")
print(decoded_string)

sourceText = "Al BaÅ£á¸©ah"
sourceTextBytes = bytes(sourceText, 'utf-8')
print(chardet.detect(sourceTextBytes))
decoded_string2 = sourceTextBytes.decode("utf")
print("Result2=", decoded_string2)
```

Output of above:

```
abc
{'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.9690625, 'language': ''}
Result2= Al BaÅ£á¸©ah
```

The output is same as the input.  I've tried ascic, utf8, etc... as the parms for the decode statement.

Part 2 - Here's another weird one that the solution below didn't work for (these are subdivison names from an ISO document a colleague purchased.)

GÉ™dÉ™bÉ™y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a classic case of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) -- in this case it's interpreted using latin1 when it should be UTF-8:

```
>>> "Al BaÅ£á¸©ah".encode('latin1')
b'Al Ba\xc5\xa3\xe1\xb8\xa9ah'
>>> "Al BaÅ£á¸©ah".encode('latin1').decode('UTF-8')
'Al Baţḩah'
```

Code for those that want to copy/paste into a program instead of command line:

```
source_text = "Al BaÅ£á¸©ah"
print("source_text=", source_text)
encoded_source_text = source_text.encode('latin1')
decoded_text = encoded_source_text.decode('UTF-8')
print("decoded_text=", decoded_text)
```

Comment: You're a genius!  How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: years and years of sadness

Comment: @NealWalters a bunch of people collected their experience from more years of sadness and cast them into the Python library [ftfy](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/) (fixes text for you), which can go directly from garbled text: `ftfy.fix_text("Al BaÅ£á¸©ah")` → `'Al Baţḩah'`. It's not error-free (because this task is basically a guessing problem), but it's pretty good.

Comment: @lenz - cool, I used that library.  I had some that caused an error on the decode solution, but ftfy didn't decode them either.  I put a "Part 2" in my question above for a weird one that wouldn't fix.

Comment: your second one is probably `cp1252` mojibake: `>>> s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8') 'Gədəbəy'`

Comment: @Sottile - Thanks!  I guess I just have one day of sadness compared to your years and years.